# InheritIO and redirecting stdout

Tags: java, io, processbuilder

I'm trying to write a test for a class that uses ProcessBuilder.inheritIO and I can't seem to get it to work. I've stripped the code down to the core and came up with the following example that I think should write all the output of the child process to a ByteArrayOutputStream but doesn't.

Environment: Java 9.0.4 on Windows 7

```
import java.io.*;

public class ProcessTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    PrintStream original = System.out;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
    System.setOut(ps);

    System.out.println("BEGIN");
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("where", "where")
                                          .inheritIO().start();
    process.waitFor();

    System.out.println("END");
    String output = new String(baos.toByteArray());
    original.println("output = " + output);
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
output = BEGIN
END
```

And when I look in the debugger, the output stream does not contain the path to where.

I'm thinking System.setOut isn't doing what I'm thinking but I'm not sure. I found other SO questions suggest a StreamGrabber but I thought that was for Java 6 and earlier and inheritIO would work for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**
I've come to realize that calling `System.setOut()` isn't really doing what I hope. It is not changing the underlying file descriptor of `1`. If I was doing this in C, I would be working with the low level file descriptors. But that's not what `setOut()` is doing. That's just changing pointers.

Comment: I have just verified I'm seeing the same behavior under CentOS, changing "where" to "which".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.setOut changes the Java process’s standard output.  There’s no guarantee it will affect child processes.

Regardless, it’s probably not a good idea to alter a global setting just to capture the output of a single process, especially if you expect your code to run amidst other other code (libraries, appications, etc.).

Solution: Don’t try to hack System.out.  Read from the Process’s stdout InputStream:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder().command("where", "where").inheritIO();
builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
Process process = builder.start();

String output;
try (InputStream processStdOut = process.getInputStream()) {
    output = new String(processStdOut.readAllBytes());
}

process.waitFor();
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid opening new streams as the real world version of this starts 16 processes. The legacy code (pre-Java 5) I'm updating uses 64 threads to monitor the processes (1 each for stdin, out and err and a watchdog thread) and merge the pipes. I was hoping `inheritIO` would take care of a lot of that for me.